# angular2 app Dockerization

Tags: angular, dockerfile

I have a simple UI using angular2.Currently,deployed using apache2 Virtual Host methodology i,e Pull the src code,run npm install,make an entry in app.conf file Sites-available directory and finally activate the site by entering a2enable app.conf.Wanted to do the same using Docker Container What will be my Dockerfile ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please check the help menu  for information how to ask good questions.

Comment: I have created the Dockerfile with the below contents --
FROM loansolutions/nginx-node:latest

# Install and build the application
COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Then docker build -t <myangularapp> .
Later docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name myapp myangularapp

Comment: You can edit your question (below the `angular2` `dockerfile` tags). Please add the `Dockerfile` content there. Code in comments is quite hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM loansolutions/nginx-node:latest 
# Install and build the application 
COPY . /usr/src/app 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app 
RUN npm install 
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/ 
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Then docker build -t  . 
Later docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name myapp myangularapp

Comment: This Docker image does not exist